# I tried many time to install requests python module but I cant, how I fix the path error on linux pop os?

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, module

I tried to install requests python module but i had a problem with PATH, I am using pop os linux

tried to being able to install moudles but seems I have a problem with my OS.[image]

Comment: I usually encounter this when pip and python aren't referring to the same directory/version. Run `pip --version` and `python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"` to see if they share the same directory.

Comment: If you have multiple pips and pythons installed, and you're not sure you're picking up the right one. you can invoke pip with "python -m pip" and see if that helps.

Also, why not just address the warning message and add the mentioned directory to your path?